# TOTAL is correct but rows are missing

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am stuck with a problem which I am not able to solve. It is About MS PowerBI. I have the following Data (everything in one Table):

- Product_ID
- Production_date
- Sales_date
- Amount Sales (which is for every row in the table "1" -->because
  every product in the table was sold)

And the following two Measures:

- Sales_amount_thisMonth
- Sales_amount_lastMonth
- EndofMonth (which gives me the last date within the next 3 months)

For every *Product_ID* there is a *Production_date* and a *Sales_date*. In my Measures I calculate the Amount of *Product_IDs* with 2 given DATESBETWEEN()-Filters. For **Sales_amount_thisMonth**:

- Sales_amount_thisMonth = CALCULATE(SUM('Products'[Amount Sales]);DATESBETWEEN('Products'[Sales_date];STARTOFMONTH('Products'[Production_date]);ENDOFMONTH('Products'[Production_date]))

And for **Sales_amount_lastMonth**:

- Sales_amount_thisMonth = CALCULATE(SUM('Products'[Amount Sales]);
  DATESBETWEEN('Products'[Production_date];STARTOFMONTH(PREVIOUSMONTH('Products'[Production_date]));ENDOFMONTH(PREVIOUSMONTH('Products'[Production_date])));
  DATESBETWEEN('Products'[Sales_date];STARTOFMONTH(PREVIOUSMONTH('Products'[Production_date]));[EndofMonth]))

For example I want to know which Product_IDs were produced in April AND sold between April and July and I want to know which products where produced in May AND sold between May and August (this is what the 2 Measures should do). I need those two numbers for comparison for the given month. Now i want to display both Measures in a Report as follows:  [my Report in PowerBi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJkBd.png)   So as you can see, I can adjust the slider and select the month I want to compare to the previous month.

Now to my PROBLEM:
Both Totals are correct; there were 188 sold Product_IDs which where produced in April and the Sales_date is between April and July and there where 313 sold ProductIDs which were produced in May and sold between May and August. And the rows for the Sales_amount_thisMonth are all correct, BUT there are rows missing for Sales_amount_lastMonth. So the Total is correct, but I am not shown all of my Sales-amount_latMonth. I thought that the Problem was between the selected month in the slider and the month in the DATESBETWEEN()-filter. But as it turns out that is not the case.

So I could really use some help here. Could somebody please give me some insight on how to fix this issue or where the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datesbetween function creates a table with dates between which then it's possible that it can be filtering some records based on the combination of your product and sales (hard to tell without looking at the full data).

You can achieve the same result by using the EOMONTH function and simple comparisons:

```
Sales_amount_thisMonth = 
//on each row this will be only one value, but on the total you'll have more
VAR productionDate = LASTDATE('Products'[Production_date]) 

RETURN CALCULATE(
  SUM('Products'[Amount Sales]),
   //greater than last day of the previous month (-1) 
   //so that puts you in all cases for current month
  'Products'[Sales_date] > EOMONTH(productionDate,-1)
  && 'Products'[Sales_date] <= EOMONTH(productionDate,0))
```

You can chose the interval you need by manipulating the second parameter of the [EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/eomonth-function-dax) function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i´m afraid it does not work. I took your Code and wrote the following to get what i want: 
`Sales_amount_lastMonth = VAR productionDate = LASTDATE('Products'[Production_date]) 
RETURN CALCULATE(SUM('Products'[Amount Sales]) 'Products'[Production_date] > EOMONTH(productionDate,-2) && 'Products'[Production_date] <= EOMONTH(productionDate,-1)&&'Products'[Sales_date] > EOMONTH(productionDate,-2)
  && 'Products'[Sales_date] <= EOMONTH(productionDate,2))`

Comment: But i still get the wrong rows in the visualization.

Comment: I think i figured out the problem, but i don´t have a solution.
I use the Production_date in the slider-visualisation to select the date-range i want to consider. For the values in my Sales_amount_lastMonth-Measure i do not want to use the (in the slider) displayed month BUT the previous month to the showing month. As it turns out, PowerBi does not understand this (at least i don´t know how to write it). But i Need the displayed Production_date for the clculation in my Sales_amount_lastMonth-Measure.

Comment: How can i use the Production_date for my calculation, but exclude the displayed Dates in the slider visualisation within my measure?
Thank you so much :)

Comment: when you do this `VAR productionDate = LASTDATE('Products'[Production_date])` you get whatever value is selected in the slider, but then you can apply functions to it, so for example `productionDate = EDATE(productionDate,-1)` moves it to previous month. Not sure that answers your question

Comment: Hello Joao, thank you for your support. I figured it aout and solved the Problem :)

Comment: If the answer helped you please mark as approved :)